# Unsuccessful in trying to start Selenium IDE recording from C# code

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide

I'm working with Selenium WebDriver (3 latest, Chrome driver, 83 latest) in C# (windows10, .net fw 4.6.2). I'm trying to start the IDE recording from within the code of a running automation test, on the open web page, (my intention is to record all the actions being done within the automation test), but with no success.

I'm trying to do it using the IDE extension API (I don't want that the IDE will be actually open during the test, nor do I want it to reopen the page for recording, since it is already open by the automation test)

My final intention is to use the outcome of the IDE recording for something I need.

Here is my C# code:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;

namespace IDE
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            
            // Load IDE extension to chrome
            options.AddExtension(@"C:\Users\<my user name>\Downloads\extension_3_17_0_0.crx"); 

            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

            // Start IDE recording           
 ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("chrome.runtime.sendMessage(\"mooikfkahbdckldjjndioackbalphokd\", {uri: \"/record/session\", verb: \"post\", payload: {url: 'https://www.google.com'}});");
   
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com");
            driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

            // Do some more actions
            // ......

            // Stop the IDE recording
  ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("chrome.runtime.sendMessage(\"mooikfkahbdckldjjndioackbalphokd\", {uri: \"/record/session\", verb: \"delete\"});");

            driver.Quit();
        }
    }
}
```

I can see that the IDE extension is loaded, but the "chrome.runtime.sendMessage" is always throwing an exception (no matter what I supply as a value to its parameters) : **"Cannot read property 'sendMessage' of undefined"**. The code I pasted here is just an example. I tried many other variations of "chrome.runtime.sendMessage". All of them threw the same exception.

I've seen a few discussions over the net about that exception in relation to my issue, but they all mention some java script files that have to be changed (manifest, content, etc.), which I'm not sure how to combine their suggestions with my code as it is in C#.

What am I missing here?
Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks!!!

Comment: I'm new to this site... please see if u can help...

Comment: I am still waiting for anyone who could help. My question is very detailed and explained well. So is the code that can be pasted as is to the efitor. If I can narrow it to one sentence it would be: How do i use the Selenium IDE api from the web driver in c# code?

Answer (score 0):

I am still waiting for anyone who could help. My question is very detailed and well explained. So is the code, that can be easily pasted, as is, to the editor (Just have the relevant refereces and the CRX file in your machine). If I can narrow it to one sentence, it would be: "How do I use the Selenium IDE API from the web driver in C# code?"